# How to flag a data change between rows for each repeated ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Stuck with an excel where in any change in data when compared with previous value in column should be flagged(boolean 1 if any change) for same id looking .
I know excel is not right tool for such, but anyway to achieve this would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Easily doable with conditional formatting.

Comment: Can you please share the approach @BigBen

Comment: `=--AND(A2=A1,C2<>C1)`, something like that if you're looking at customer and city.

Answer (score -1):

How about a nested if statement like the following?

=IF(A2=A1, IF(C2=C1, 0, 1), 0)